# How to set user type in a customuser model when a new user registers

Tags: python, django

I have two models `CustomUser` and `Manager_profile` given below. There are 2 types of users a manager and a customer. There is a form to register as a manager. How can I set the is_manager field to True when a manager registers?

I also have another question. How can I store the data from `department` field to the `Manager_profile` model?

#Models

```
 class CustomUser(AbstractUser):                         
      is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

 class Manager_profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
      department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.department
```

#Form

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from account.models import CustomUser
from django import forms

class ManagerCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    department = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:    
         model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','department']
```

Comment: Try initialising the 'is_manager' field in the forms.py. is_manager = forms.BooleanField(initial = True)

Comment: Did you solve problem?

Comment: Yes I solved it.